# SQL join not returning the correct data

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to build some test cases in SQL. The problem is when I'm trying to join some table with a left join (which if my understanding is correct should return both the matching and nonmatching row) when I'm trying to get the data with no matching ID, no data is returned.

Here is the code:

```
select
      E.ID_EVENEMENT,
      t1.dateRecente as date_Star,
      virage_c.no_contr,
      t2.id as id_Univers,
      t2.dateRecente as date_Univers,
      t3.NUMERO_DOSSIER_STAR,
      t3.dateRecente as Date_factcan,
      t3.dateLimite,
      t2.ID_PERSONNE_UNIVERS,
      t1.ID_PERSONNE_STAR
   FROM
      STAR.EVENEMENT e
         left join VIRAGE.CONTRAT virage_c 
            on e.NO_CONTRAT_OFFICIEL = to_char(virage_c.no_contr)
         inner join 
         ( SELECT
                 e.ID_EVENEMENT,
                 ep.ID_EVEN_INDIVIDU as ID_PERSONNE_STAR,
                 GREATEST( e.dt_creation,
                           NVL(e.DT_MODIF_STA_ELI, TO_DATE(1,'j')),
                           NVL(max(nt.dt_maj), TO_DATE(1,'j')),
                           NVL(max(ser.DT_CREATION), TO_DATE(1,'j')),
                           NVL(max(SER.DT_MAJ), TO_DATE(1,'j')),
                           NVL(max(aut.dt_transmis), TO_DATE(1,'j')),
                           NVL(max(AUT.DT_CREATION), TO_DATE(1,'j')) ) dateRecente
              FROM 
                 STAR.EVENEMENT e
                    left join STAR.Note nt 
                       on e.ID_EVENEMENT = nt.ID_EVEN
                    left join STAR.SERVICE ser 
                       on e.ID_EVENEMENT = ser.ID_EVEN
                       left join STAR.AUTORISATION aut 
                          on ser.id_service = aut.id_service
                    left join STAR.DOCUMENT doc 
                       on e.ID_EVENEMENT = doc.ID_EVENEMENT
                    left join STAR.ETAT ett 
                       on e.ID_EVENEMENT = ett.ID_EVENEMENT
                    left join STAR.EVENEMENT_PARTICIPANT ep 
                       on e.ID_EVENEMENT = ep.ID_EVENEMENT
              GROUP BY 
                 e.ID_EVENEMENT,
                 e.dt_creation,
                 e.DT_MODIF_STA_ELI,
                 ep.ID_EVEN_INDIVIDU ) t1 
                 on t1.ID_EVENEMENT = E.ID_EVENEMENT
         left JOIN 
         ( SELECT
                 sf.STAREVENTNUMBER,
                 c.id,
                 par.ID as ID_PERSONNE_UNIVERS,
                 GREATEST( c.UPDATEDATE,
                           max(NVL(ca.UPDATEDATE, TO_DATE(1, 'J'))),
                           max(NVL(bo.UPDATEDATE, TO_DATE(1, 'J'))),
                           max(NVL(a.UPDATEDATE, TO_DATE(1, 'J'))),
                           max(NVL(p.UPDATEDATE, TO_DATE(1, 'J'))),
                           max(NVL(p.RELEASEDATE, TO_DATE(1, 'J'))),
                           max(NVL(p.PAYMENTDATE, TO_DATE(1, 'J'))) ) dateRecente
              FROM
                 CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.STAR_FILE sf
                    join CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.CLAIM c 
                       on sf.claimid = c.id
                       left join CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.BENEFIT_OPTION bo 
                          on c.id = BO.CLAIMID
                          left join CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.ADJUDICATION a 
                             on bo.id = a.BENEFITOPTIONID     
                       left join CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.CLAIM_ACTIVITY ca 
                          on c.id = CA.CLAIMID
                       left join CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.CLAIM_RELATIONSHIP cr 
                          on c.id = CR.CLAIMID
                          left join CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.PAYEE pa 
                             on cr.id = PA.CLAIMRELATIONSHIPID
                             left join CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.PAYMENT p 
                                on pa.id = P.PAYEEID
                    left join CV_CLAIMS_TRAVEL.PARTY par 
                       on par.ID = sf.PARTYID
              WHERE
                     c.PRIMARYSTATUSLID in ('CLAIM_PRIMARY_STATUS:0000000003','CLAIM_PRIMARY_STATUS:0000000001') 
                 OR (   c.PRIMARYSTATUSLID = 'CLAIM_PRIMARY_STATUS:0000000004' 
                    AND bo.BENEFITOPTIONSTATUSLID in ('BENEFIT_OPTION_STATUS:0000000010', 
                                                      'BENEFIT_OPTION_STATUS:0000000060', 
                                                      'BENEFIT_OPTION_STATUS:0000000030')
                    )
              group by 
                 sf.STAREVENTNUMBER, 
                 c.id, 
                 c.UPDATEDATE, 
                 par.ID ) t2 
            on e.ID_EVENEMENT = t2.STAREVENTNUMBER
         LEFT JOIN 
         ( SELECT DISTINCT
                 fact.NUMERO_DOSSIER_STAR,
                 GREATEST( to_date(fact.VSTDTCHG,'yyyymmdd'),
                           to_date(fact.VSTDICHK,'yyyymmdd'),
                           to_date(decode(fact.VSTDIFIN,0,19000101,
                                decode(substr(fact.VSTDIFIN,5),
                                '0230', substr(fact.VSTDIFIN,1,4) 
                                || '0301',fact.VSTDIFIN)),'yyyymmdd') ) DateRecente,
                 DECODE( virage_cont.id_cont,
                         null,add_months(sysdate,-7*12),
                         add_months(sysdate,-15*12)) dateLimite
              FROM
                 FACTCAN.XC4DSAV fact
                    LEFT JOIN VIRAGE.CONTRAT virage_cont 
                       on fact.VSTNOCNT_VIRAGE = virage_cont.NO_CONTR
              where 
                 fact.NUMERO_DOSSIER_STAR is not null ) t3 
            on e.ID_EVENEMENT = t3.NUMERO_DOSSIER_STAR
   WHERE
          t1.dateRecente < add_months(sysdate, -7*12) 
      AND t2.dateRecente < add_months(sysdate, -7*12) 
      AND virage_c.id_cont is null 
      AND t2.ID_PERSONNE_UNIVERS is not null 
      AND t1.ID_PERSONNE_STAR is null 
      AND t3.dateRecente < t3.dateLimite
   FETCH 
      FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

When I'm trying to get the results from an event with either
t1.ID_PERSONNE_STAR or t2.ID_PERSONNE_UNIVERS is null, the query isn't returning anything when it should in fact return some data. The is not null works as intended though. Any idea?

Comment: When using `left join`, you have to be careful about filtering out the unmatched records in the `where` clause.

Comment: You have use `AND` in condition - `t2.ID_PERSONNE_UNIVERS is not null AND t1.ID_PERSONNE_STAR is null`. So you will get data if both the conditions are right.

Comment: Yes thats the point but  when either one of those condition is null, no data is returned.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff has said - if you use a where clause to explicitly filter rows from the outer joined table you effectively turn the join into an inner join. I suspect that is your problem. You can try adding the not null condition to the JOIN clause instead - I'm told that is a potential work-round .

Comment: Remove conditions from the `WHERE` clause except for `t1.dateRecente < add_months(sysdate, -7*12)` and `t1.ID_PERSONNE_STAR is null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the readability of the query.  Also, as noted by others, you have to be careful about the WHERE clause.  The issue you are probably running into is your where clauses for the T1, T2 and T3 for left-joins...  Move these up to those joins...  ex

where you have

```
   left join (rest of the left-join subquery with alias ) t1 
     on t1.ID_EVENEMENT = E.ID_EVENEMENT
```

change to

```
 on t1.ID_EVENEMENT = E.ID_EVENEMENT
 AND t1.dateRecente < add_months(sysdate, -7*12)
```

This way, the date requirement is part of the LEFT-JOIN.  By having that in the WHERE clause is turning it into an INNER JOIN.

You can leave the T1 "IS NULL" test at the where clause portion because you are explicitly expecting no matching records.

Check similar situations for your other left-joins... move the CRITERIA to the JOIN/ON clause and remove from the WHERE.  The where clause SHOULD have the "IS NULL" for final expectation.